# Laravel - Match test directory to app directory

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I have a pretty big Laravel 5.6 application I'm currently developing. By default, Larvel comes with a `tests` directory along with a `tests/Unit` and `tests/Feature` sub directories.

- When I first started developing my app, any test I wrote that didn't require a full HTTP life cycle to take place, I would put in the `tests/Unit` directory.

  - *Example:* Testing a custom local query scope on a model.
- Similarly, any test that did require a full HTTP life cycle I would put in the `tests/Feature` directory.

  - *Example:* Testing controllers using a `GET`, `POST`, etc request and making sure I got back a 200 response or equivalent.

Now that my application has grown to be quite massive, I'm starting to think that there should be a better way to organize my `tests` directory. I'm also noticing that parts of my code base do not have test coverage based on reports from codecov.io.

In my mind, it would make sense to create a `tests/App` directory and have that mirror all my files and classes in the `app` directory of the project root. Each class and/or file would have a corresponding test. This way, I'll have a better idea of which parts of my app have test coverage and which ones do not. I haven't seen any other projects that do this so I'm hesitant to apply this approach.

So, to summarize my question:

**Are there any pitfalls with structuring the tests directory exactly like the app directory?**

**Is there an alternative way to structure your test directory so that you can tell with ease which classes/files have corresponding tests?**

*Side Note: I'm well aware that my unit tests don't adhere to the "normal" convention of mocking out your dependencies and testing in isolation. This is a separate issue but in short I feel that mocking doesn't allow you to refactor you code with ease. More info on what I'm talking about in my defense: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdUKfbG713M*

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using the structure that Laravel provided. but I have made little changes. for example for functional testing, I have added an admin folder so I can write tests for admin APIs or for unit testing I have added (unit/cron, unit/middleware, unit/jobs, ...) this way I can control the directories.

tests/functional/admin

tests/unit/cron

tests/unit/middleware

tests/unit/jobs

tests/unit/policy

tests/unit/models
...

And also to see which API or function has a test or not it's a little hard to have it. If you are following the TDD principle then no need to worry about this part because you know that everyone who writes a piece of code he/she will write the test for it. but if you are not following the TDD and you have just started with writing tests for your project then you need to run PHPUnit coverage with --HTML tag and it'll return for you the HTML graph which can tell you how much code coverage your project has.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you know if I need to have xdebug enabled in order to generate code coverage?

Comment: Yes you should have Xdebug, you can use Xdebug but I recommend you to use Phpdbg instead of Xdebug, take a look at this link it'll help you a lot regarding running tests with different commands https://medium.com/@nicocabot/speed-up-phpunit-code-coverage-analysis-4e35345b3dad

Comment: This looks great. I didn't know Phpdbg was a thing. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All Laravel projects start from an initial template,
if you check the `phpunit.xml` which the template normally includes, you should find:

```
...

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

All this does is tell `PHPUnit` to execute/run `Unit` folder's tests before `Feature` folder's tests.

The reason for that being;

- If a **normally small** `Unit` is failing any test,
- Then it makes no sense to search for the bug in **normally large** Feature(s),
- And PHPUnit's report shows Unit folder's test-results at top,
  which suggests that those should be fixed first, because debugging an entire Feature is normally harder than debugging a small Unit.

### Example

Knowing above should help you decide for yourself;

But if you ask me, I would simply create an `App` folder in `Unit` folder, or add an additional `testsuite` to `phpunit.xml` file, right after `Unit` entry, like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="App">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/App</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

> Because having one test-file beside each php-file is a Unit-testing style, not Feature-testing, even if the test requires "full HTTP life cycle".